# XML Rss parsing

Tags: iphone

Looking for a full XML RSS tutorial

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668762/displaying-content-from-an-rss-feed-in-an-iphone-app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566078/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-for-an-iphone-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613153/best-xml-parser-for-rss-feeds-in-objective-c

Comment: Oops...Thank for navigation shaggy Frog.

Comment: Flagging this question as off topic because it is asking for a library recommendation.